# Different roles for folders and files in Google Drive (GSuite)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-apps, google-apps-for-education

I have a GSuite with user groups, every group is one department in the organisation. I got the following permissions now:

- Every department can edit his own folder
- Every department can view folders of the other departments

Only I want that every department who can view something, also can comment on GDoc files and Spreadsheet files. I know I can change this on every file indiviually, but our Drive has over 1000 GDoc files. I'm not going by every old (and new) file to change this permission everytime.

I tried to solve this with a script and tried

- file.addCommenter(email); -> Invalid argument: permission.value
- file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.PRIVATE, DriveApp.Permission.COMMENT) -> No error, but also no result.

Does someone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> file.addCommenter(email); -> Invalid argument: permission.value

That's a tricky one. There is an [open issue #4231](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4231) since July 2014 (!) about this. I have not personally encountered this, but apparently it is an issue, though may be a rare one. Is it a specific file type that this fails on? I have just tested `file.addCommenter(email)` on all Google file types, and it worked without an issue for me.

Is the account your script is executing under the OWNER of these files, or only has 'EDIT' access to them? Has the option 'Prevent editors from changing access and adding new people' been enabled for these files? These are some things I would start checking to pinpoint the cause of the issue.

If all else fails, I suggest you contact Google Support rep with this - there should be a link for this in your GSuite Admin Control Panel.

> file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.PRIVATE, DriveApp.Permission.COMMENT)
>   -> No error, but also no result.

I do not think this will do what you expect it to. [`setSharing()` method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setsharingaccesstype-permissiontype) sets the sharing properties of the file *besides any individual users who have been explicitly given access*. Basically, `setSharing()` method will not change the sharing access of users who have already been explicitly granted some level of access to the file.

The way you could potentially use it, is to grant COMMENT access to the file to any user in your domain using `file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.DOMAIN_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.COMMENT)`, provided you are GSuite for Business or EDU user.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ah thanks it works! Do you know how I can turn off all email notifications?

Comment: AFAIK changing permissions/sharing through Google Script will always send notifications - there is no way to disable that.